# Get Filename from email attachment in Python

Tags: python, email, attachment

I am loggin into a server with my credentials and I search for an email with specific subject.  This certain email has an attachment which I want to know its filename and possibly extension later on.

I am doing this in Python but everytime ask for the filename, it returns NONE when in fact there is a filename in the attachment.

```
from imaplib import *
import base64
import email
import os
import sys
import errno
import mimetypes




server = IMAP4("SERVER LOCATION");

server.login("USER", "PASS");
server.select("Inbox");

typ, data = server.search(None, '(SUBJECT "Hello World")');

for num in data[0].split():
    typ, data = server.fetch(num, '(RFC822)');
    print (data);
    msg = email.message_from_string(str(data[0][1]));

      counter = 1
for part in msg.walk():
    print (part.as_string() + "\n")
    # multipart/* are just containers
    if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
        continue
    # Applications should really sanitize the given filename so that an
    # email message can't be used to overwrite important files
    filename = part.get_filename()


    print (filename);

    fn = msg.get_filename()

    print("The Filename was:", (fn));


    if not filename:
        ext = mimetypes.guess_extension(part.get_content_type())


                        if not ext:
            # Use a generic bag-of-bits extension
            ext = '.bin'
            filename = 'part-%03d%s' % (counter, ext)
    counter += 1


server.close()


server.logout();
```

I don't know why I keep getting NONE as an answer, any help?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, here is what I did to solve it :

```
if msg.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart': #multipart messages only
    # loop on the parts of the mail
    for part in msg.walk():
        #find the attachment part - so skip all the other parts
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart': continue
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'text': continue
        if part.get('Content-Disposition') == 'inline': continue
        if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None: continue

        #save the attachment in the program directory
        print "part:", part.as_string()
        filename = part.get_filename()
        print "filename :", filename
        filepath = DIR_SBD+filename
        fp = open(filepath, 'wb')
        fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
        fp.close()
        print '%s saved!' % filepath
```

Answer (score 2):

## You need to first check

```
for part in msg.walk():

    print (part.get_content_type())
```

and then in the main for loop -

```
for part in msg.walk():
```

just continue for the content types that are present in the mail body but are not required by you.

You can also put a check directly for the content_type required and then read the filename.

ex -I faced a same problem and my content types were *multipart* and *text/html* and *application/json*

I did not put the check for text/html and wanted to read the attachment which was in "*application/json*". I was directly reading the filename and hence the error - filename None was coming.

When I put the check-
`

```
if part.get_content_maintype() == 'text/html':
    continue

if part.get('Content-Type')== 'application/json':

    filename = part.get_filename().split('.')

#do the stuff needed
```

`
No error would come.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

If you dump everything in "part" do you actually see the file there?

Comment: I see the file in the DOS menu when I do-- print(part);  If this is what you mean by dump, I'm a beginner in python, picked it up yesterday. I also get this KSH file in the place where I saved this python script if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Okay, well if you can see it in there, you're probably not accessing it the right way.

Comment: how would I access it, i have tried the get_filename() but it returns none even though get_content_type() returns text/plain which is correct.. thanks so far though for the assistance

Comment: I'm guessing you're using the code from here: http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html

Looks like you've got some lines to add still. Look to the bit starting with "if not filename:" I think that's dealing with what you're running in to in testing.. No?

Comment: Yea I am using the code from the python documentation.  I thought that the part you referred me to would be used to upload/send an email but I will try it when I get in tomorrow nonetheless.  Thanks alot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar problem. Just remove 
if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
        continue
condition and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue with answers above ... plus I just printed results in the loop:

```
for part in msg.walk():
    print('content type: %s' % part.get_content_type())
    print('filename: %s' % part.get_filename())
```

Then identify which content part has the file name:

```
content type: multipart/mixed
filename: None
content type: multipart/alternative
filename: None
content type: text/plain
filename: None
content type: text/html
filename: None
content type: application/octet-stream
filename: XXXXX__202307141059.csv
```

Now code:

```
for part in msg.walk():
    if part.get_content_type() == 'application/octet-stream':
        file_name = part.get_filename()
```